# Check if url exists using Laravel

Tags: php, url, laravel-5.1

How can I check if an url exists in laravel 5.1?

For example, I want to check if `www.google.com` exists.

```
$url ="www.google.com";
if(exists(url)){
     // do something
}
```

What function or code can I use to return true for the above example?

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel you can use use `GuzzleHttp\Client` as such:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();
$request = $client->head('http://google.com/');

if( $request->getStatusCode() == 200 ) {
    // Do something ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use normal PHP code in laravel.

Use [`get_headers()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.get-headers.php) function, it returns false if the given domain is not registered.

```
$url = 'http://google.com/';
if(get_headers($url))
    // do something
```

And don't forget the HTTP (http://) protocol prepending the domain.

Comment: @Wendy Liem please accept the as solution.

Comment: `get_headers()` will become `TRUE` if server returns error codes (like 404).

Comment: But we don't want to get error codes, we just want to know if the url exists

Comment: Yes, but you can get headers for non-existing urls (like server-side generated 404 pages).

Example: while checking "stackoverflow.com/NotExisting" you will get "TRUE", becouse headers will be sent, but this is not a valid address.

Comment: You are right! But well there are 2 possibilities, i guess that he wants to know if the domain exists (is registered). In that case `get_headers()` fits totally in. In the case you want to know if a file on the server exists you have to choose another way. Since he said 'it works' it might be the right solution ;)